# Angular - Get Component's DOM Element without injecting ElementRef

Tags: javascript, angular

Say I have a parent component:

```
@Component({...})
ParentComponent{
}
```

And a child component:

```
@Component({...})
ChildComponent{
    constructor(parent:ParentComponent){}
}
```

In the child component, I can inject `ParentComponent` like the above. However, it gives the class instance, not DOM Element. What if I want to get the parent's DOM?

If I have control of the parent class, I can just inject `ElementRef` in the parent component. But what about the cases when you don't have control of the parent class?

Comment: What for you want to get ElementRef?

Comment: DOM manipulation.

Comment: If you don't have control over parent, a directive can be added to parent to communicate with it. If this is not possible, it should be reached through Renderer2 provider (parentNode method). What is exactly the case you're trying to solve?

Comment: The latter. So I can use Renderer2 to get the parent node? When I'm not sure how many levels to go up to find the parent, it's much work.

Comment: @Shawn - the parent is always one level up. What's beyond one level is not the element's parent anymore.

Comment: Sorry I mean ancestor. You can easily get its class instance through DI but no easy way to get its dom element?

Comment: I'd argue that it's a good thing you're forced to inject `elementRef`. You can grab ViewChild and ContentChild's `ElementRef` without injecting it in the child component, but not the other way around. This is because components should not depend on their parents. The question is _why_ do you want to do this?

If you want to manipulate DOM, inject the elementRef in the child and use native DOM API to manipulate the structure. Also consider using a structual directive instead.